# A word for an individual who feels that compliments that he receives are always backhanded

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe an individual who believes that the compliments that he receives are always backhanded?

For example, let's say an individual who is part of a soccer team receives a compliment for good performance in a match that his team won. However, the individual is sceptical of his own performance in the match and therefore reckons that the compliment was backhanded.

Comment: Perhaps *Insecure*.

Comment: I would recommend you to include a sentence or context in which you would use the word. ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***.

Comment: Marv has the  answer with 'cynical' (in the sense of 'prone to put the worst possible interpretation on another's behaviour'), but the root problem is really pride. This is an inverted manifestation of pride: knowing that you know better than everyone else. You're the final arbiter in all debates. You decide what's right, what's wrong (erroneous and/or immoral). Essentially, original sin.

Comment: That reminds me of people who exercise extreme self-restraint—those weak individuals that can't resist the temptation to deny themselves a pleasure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  My breath is taken by your leap of logic. Do all acts of self deprecation, in your view, stem from one of the seven deadly sins?

Comment: @WS2 I don't know :) Seriously, I'd say they cover most of the basics between them. There's the less detailed analysis into the desire to indulge, the desire to possess / control, and pride (aka lust of the flesh ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ['cynical'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cynical?s=t)

> Cynical - **adjective**
>
> 1 - distrusting or disparaging the motives of others; like or characteristic of a cynic.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*